# How to select statistics table counting occurrences between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to count occurrences of protocol violations and durations between 2 dates from table to achieve effect like statistics table which will look like at the picture below:

### Expected effect:

[image]

### Explanation:

As you can see I need to select 'Country', 'Site' existing in Violations table and: 'Numbers', 'Maximum', 'Minimum' and 'Mean' of protocol violations duration existing in DB in the same table 'Violations' **between two dates**. So we have to count:

- protocol violations **occurrences** existing in Violations table by country and site
- min/max/avg **durations** of protocol violations by country and site

under two different conditions:

- occurrences from **Date Discovered to Date Reported**
- occurrences from **Date Reported to Date Confirmed**

### Database Structure:

Available at SQLFILDDLE: [Look HERE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46249/1/0)

I will add that code in attached SQLFIDDLE has more tables and an query but they are unnecessary right now for this problem. Feel free to use it. 
I didn't remove old query because there is nice way to do:

- '- All -' and
- '- Unknown -' values. -

### Violation table:

```
create table violations (
  id long,
  country varchar(20),
  site varchar(20),
  status_id int,
  trial_id int,
  discovered_date date,
  reporded_date date,
  confirmed_date date
);
```

### Site table:

```
create table site (
  id long,
  site varchar(20)
);
```

### My First try:

Here is my new [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46249/6/0) with query needed to improve commented lines:

```
SELECT v.country as country, v.site as site,
  COUNT(*) as N --,
  --MAX(list of durations in days between discovered date to repored date on each violation by country and site) as "Maximum",
  --MIN(list of durations in days between discovered date to repored date on each violation by country and site) as "Minimum",
  --AVG(list of durations in days between discovered date to repored date on each violation by country and site) as "Mean"
FROM violations v
WHERE v.trial_id = 3
GROUP BY ROLLUP (v.country, v.site)
```

I've managed to create abstract query with my idea. But I have a problem to write correct query for MAX, MIN and AVG where we must select max/min/avg value from list of durations in days between `discovered date` to `reported date` on each violation by country and site.

Could you help me please?

Comment: It seems that you need to calc. number of violations by site. Is this correct? If so, all you need is select count, min/max and group by country and site where your_date between trunc(start_date) and trunc(end_date). Or do you need more then this? What is the problem here? Joins or calculations? Judging by expected result you posted all you need is to count/min/max and group by...

Comment: @Art Thanks for you suggestion. I've added abstract query and commented lines problematic for me. The problem is calculations, how to count max/min/avg duration of violation based on my requirements (count from date to date by country and site)? I do not know if I am trying to do it in correct way, could you take a look at this query? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46249/6

Comment: I've edited question description maybe now it will be more clear..

Answer (score 0):

Please check this query. It is simplified and may give you an idea and direction. If you need more then this then let me know. Copy and paste to see results. This query will select and calc only the results between two dates in where clause. You need to run inner query first w/out where to see all dates etc... This query counts violations between 2 dates. Not sure what is the list of duration in days... See below for count of duration. You may add MAX/MIN etc...

```
-- Days between (duration) = (end_date-start_date) = number of days (number) --
SELECT (to_date('14-MAR-2013') - to_date('01-MAR-2013')) days_between
  FROM dual
/


SELECT country, site
 , Count(*) total_viol
 , MAX(susp_viol) max_susp_viol
 , MIN(susp_viol) min_susp_viol
FROM
(
 SELECT 'GERMANY' country, '12222' site, 1 susp_viol, 2 conf_viol, trunc(Sysdate-30) disc_date, trunc(Sysdate-25) conf_date
   FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'GERMANY',  '12222'            , 3          , 14, trunc(Sysdate-20) , trunc(Sysdate-15)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'GERMANY',  '12222'            , 6          , 25, trunc(Sysdate-20) , trunc(Sysdate-15)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'GERMANY',  '12222'            , 2          , 1, trunc(Sysdate-20) , trunc(Sysdate-15)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'GERMANY',  '13333'            , 10         , 5,  trunc(Sysdate-15) , trunc(Sysdate-10)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'GERMANY',  '13333'            , 15         , 3,  trunc(Sysdate-15) , trunc(Sysdate-10)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'GERMANY',  'Unknown Site'     , 0          , 7,  trunc(Sysdate-5) ,  trunc(Sysdate-2)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'RUSSIA',  '12345'             , 1          , 5,  trunc(Sysdate-20) ,  trunc(Sysdate-15)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'RUSSIA',  '12345'             , 2          , 10,  trunc(Sysdate-15) ,  trunc(Sysdate-12)  FROM dual
 UNION
SELECT 'RUSSIA',  'Unknown Site'      , 10          , 10,  trunc(Sysdate-3) ,  trunc(Sysdate-1)  FROM dual
 ) 
  -- replace sysdate with your_date-default format is to_date('14-MAR-2013') or give format mask
 WHERE conf_date BETWEEN trunc(Sysdate-20) AND trunc(Sysdate-10)
 GROUP BY ROLLUP (country, site)
 ORDER BY country, site
/
```

Count of duration:

```
SELECT country, site, (conf_date-disc_date) duration, count(*) total_durations 
  FROM
 (
 SELECT 'GERMANY' country, '12222' site, 1 susp_viol, 2 conf_viol, trunc(Sysdate-30) disc_date, trunc(Sysdate-20) conf_date
   FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'GERMANY',  '12222'            , 3          , 14, trunc(Sysdate-20) , trunc(Sysdate-12)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'GERMANY',  '12222'            , 6          , 25, trunc(Sysdate-20) , trunc(Sysdate-12)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'GERMANY',  '12222'            , 2          , 1, trunc(Sysdate-20) , trunc(Sysdate-12)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'GERMANY',  '13333'            , 10         , 5,  trunc(Sysdate-12) , trunc(Sysdate-6)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'GERMANY',  '13333'            , 15         , 3,  trunc(Sysdate-17) , trunc(Sysdate-11)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'GERMANY',  'Unknown Site'     , 0          , 7,  trunc(Sysdate-5) ,  trunc(Sysdate-2)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'RUSSIA',  '12345'             , 1          , 5,  trunc(Sysdate-20) ,  trunc(Sysdate-15)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'RUSSIA',  '12345'             , 2          , 10,  trunc(Sysdate-15) ,  trunc(Sysdate-12)  FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 'RUSSIA',  'Unknown Site'      , 10          , 10,  trunc(Sysdate-3) ,  trunc(Sysdate-1)  FROM dual
 ) 
 WHERE conf_date BETWEEN trunc(Sysdate-20) AND trunc(Sysdate-10) 
  GROUP BY ROLLUP (country, site, (conf_date-disc_date))
  ORDER BY country, site
 /
```